# How can I get the iPhone's CPU usage and memory usage?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory, cpu-usage

How can I programmatically get the iPhone/iPad's CPU usage and memory usage? I want to display this information in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Memory usage indication inside app 
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/07/coding-cocos/ 
"Raising awareness: memory usage & leaks"

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreak, then add SBSettings. It will show you all of that type of information.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments. Unless you mean to display directly in your app.

Comment: Haha,yes,i want show it in my app.what solution can be？
thank you very much！！